# How to kill and restart input language in macOS?

Tags: keyboard, language

These days I have been stuck in a painstaking case where an input of language is not switched to some languages. I usually use English, Simplified Chinese, and Japanese, but Japanese input language input has suddenly been unable to be switched on.

This can be fixed on restart, but it is a pain to restart every time so I would rather like to know a way, if any, to just kill and restart the input language.

For example, a command such as `killall Finder` or `killall Dock`.